# Override ArrayBuffer.contains() method in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm new to Scala, and I want to check a if a `String` exists in an `ArrayBuffer[String]`, but in **case insensitive**. So I was thinking create a new class extends `ArrayBuffer[String]` and use the Java String method `equalsIgnoreCase()`
for example:

```
MyArrayBuffer("smallint", "INt", "varchar").contains("int")
```

the class is like this:

```
class MyArrayBuffer[String]() extends ArrayBuffer[String] {
    def containsCaseIns(str: String): Boolean = {
      for (s <- this) {
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
          true;
      }
      false;
    }
  }
```

But I failed with an compile error `"value equalsIgnoreCase is not a member of type parameter String"`

So how can I fix it? or is there any way better to do it?

Comment: Hint: how do you declare a generic class in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a subclass here is unnecessary.  You can implement this functionality easily using existing methods

```
val buff = ArrayBuffer("smallint", "INt", "varchar")
buff.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("int")) //true
```

exists takes a condition and returns true if at least one element satisfies the condition.

If you think it nicer to add a method "containsIgnoreCase" to ArrayBuffer[String], you can do that as well quite easily without subclassing using extension methods, sometimes referred to as the "enhance my library" pattern.  You achieve this be adding the method to an implicit class.

```
object Extensions {
  implicit class EnhancedStringBuffer(val underlying: ArrayBuffer[String]) extends AnyVal {
      def containsIgnoreCase(elem: String): Boolean = underlying.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase(elem))
  }
}
```

Now this works

```
 import Extensions._
 ArrayBuffer("smallint", "INt", "varchar").containsIgnoreCase("int") //true
```

Because it's a value type you don't incur any extra runtime object allocation costs. You can even make it more generic, use `GenTraversableOnce[String]` as the type for underlying and then you can use this new method for any collection of strings.

Note that these methods run in O(n) time complexity (exists does short circuit once it finds a match, so it doesn't always need a full traversal).  If you are collecting a large amount of strings, and need to do a contains check often, you may want to take a different approach entirely.  In this case, a hashset where you just convert all entries to uppercase as you enter them might be your best bet.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class CaseInsensitiveStrings {

  private[this] val strings = new mutable.HashSet[String]()

  def addString(elem: String) = strings.add(elem.toUpperCase)

  def contains(elem: String) = strings.contains(elem.toUpperCase)

}
```

This probably isn't worth doing if you only have a relatively small set of strings or you aren't doing this contains check very often, but if that is the case a hashset will allow efficient lookups against even large sets of strings.  It means you can't store multiples of the same case-insensitive string, so you'll to change things a bit if you need that. You can add any other methods or traits you find necessary but be careful to ensure the invariant that all entries are uppercased holds true.

Answer (score 1):

Some background information on why your class fails to compile:

Your class defines a type parameter named `String` which shadows the class `java.lang.String`.

Your class would compile if you would write it as

```
class MyArrayBuffer() extends ArrayBuffer[String] {
    def containsCaseIns(str: String): Boolean = {
      for (s <- this) {
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
          true;
      }
      false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work (a is your buffer):

```
a.filter(_.equalsIgnoreCase("int")).length > 0
```

Comment: It might be even more straightforward to use `a.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("int"))`

Comment: It works, but it always checks `equalsIgnoreCase` for _all_ elements of `a` instead of stopping at the first element for which it returns `true`.

Comment: yes, it's better to use `a.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("int"))`